# String Index Out of Range

Tags: python

I am using pandas and pulling information from excel into a list, that part works great and my lists are coming back and I can print them out just fine with no NaN or errors.

However when I go to iterate through them I am encountering an issue with the string index being out of range after the first iteration or when itr is 1 as it prints the first one just fine then errors at the line `site = site[itr]`.

The site array or list if you will which is comprised of numeric values.  I get the count of the number of rows pulled from excel as the index limiter called toSend.

I added `site = [str(i) for i in site]` because I was getting the error that the int object is not subscriptable.

I'm not sure where I turned left at, any help is very much appreciated.

******* Updated to MRE as requested *******

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 
import pandas as pd
import time
name = ['Michael Jordan', 'General Clark', 'Tony Tiger', 'Alvin Chipmunk', 'Daffy Duck']
eMail = ['thebulls@bull.com', 'general@insurance.com', 'tiger@post.com', 'alvin@chipmunk.com', 'duck@goose.com']
site = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9]
site = [str(i) for i in site]
toSend = 5
print("Count is " + str(toSend))
print("Starting up... Excel Read")
print(name)
print(site)
print(eMail)
time.sleep(2)
itr = 0
for itr in range(toSend):
    print(str(itr))
    name = name[itr]
    eMail = eMail[itr]
    site = site[itr]
    print("\nWe will be sending an email statements to " + str(name) + "\nfor site " + str(site) + "\nat email address "+ str(eMail) + "\n")
    itr = int(itr) + 1
print("Listing Completed")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you attached the stack trace and the line number the error occurred.

Comment: I suspect your loop is going one iteration too far.  Python lists are zero-indexed, meaning that if you have a list with five elements, the valid indexes are `[0]` through `[4]`; attempting to access index `[5]` is an error.  Try changing your loop condition to `while itr < toSend`

Comment: If `site` is composed of numeric values converted to string, the max index of that string is the number of digits, not necessarily the number of rows in the excel file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.   
Your posted code fails on undefined symbols, and you've neglected to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

Its because you are overwriting your variables.

So `name` starts as an array:

```
name = ['Michael Jordan', 'General Clark', 'Tony Tiger', 'Alvin Chipmunk', 'Daffy Duck']
```

Loop 1, `name` becomes a string (idx = 1)

```
name = 'Michael Jordan'
```

Loop 2, `name` becomes a single letter string (idx = 2)

```
name = 'i'
```

Loop 2, `name` tries to get position 3 from a single letter string, therefore string index out of range (idx = 3)

Fixed example:

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 
import pandas as pd
import time
name = ['Michael Jordan', 'General Clark', 'Tony Tiger', 'Alvin Chipmunk', 'Daffy Duck']
eMail = ['thebulls@bull.com', 'general@insurance.com', 'tiger@post.com', 'alvin@chipmunk.com', 'duck@goose.com']
site = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9]
site = [str(i) for i in site]
toSend = 5
print("Count is " + str(toSend))
print("Starting up... Excel Read")
print(name)
print(site)
print(eMail)
time.sleep(2)
itr = 0
for itr in range(toSend):
    print(str(itr))
    loop_name = name[itr]
    loop_eMail = eMail[itr]
    loop_site = site[itr]
    print("\nWe will be sending an email statements to " + str(loop_name) + "\nfor site " + str(loop_site) + "\nat email address "+ str(loop_eMail) + "\n")
print("Listing Completed")
```

-- Old --

Just modify your code to a for loop, this will reduce the logic needed and make it easier to debug.

```
name = sI["Name"].values.tolist()
eMail = sI["MailAddress"].values.tolist()
site = sI["MailSite"].values.tolist()
site = [str(i) for i in site]
toSend = sI["Count"].values

print("Count is " + str(toSend))
print("Starting up... Excel Read")
print(name)
print(site)
print(eMail)
time.sleep(2)
itr = 0
for itr in range(len(toSend)):
    print(str(itr))
    name = name[itr]
    eMail = eMail[itr]
    site = site[itr]
    print("We will be sending an email statements to " + str(name) + "\nfor site " + str(site) + "\nat email address "+ str(eMail))
```

Comment: That does simplify the logic but didn't help the error.  I updated the code to a repeatable snippet.

Comment: @PaulHubert I have updated based on your code and provided the reason why its not working.

Comment: Excellent catch, I totally should have realized that when it made it through the first iteration and was failing on the second. Feeling a little stupid right now but  I will certainly be more aware of that mistake in the future.  Thank You!